# Is there a way to disable a css class in media queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I have a css class "fadeout" that I want to disable if viewport width less than 786px
something like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 786px) {
.fadeout {doesItWork?:noItDoesNotWork!;}
}
```

You see the class does something regarding " $(window).scrollTop(); " in jquery which i don't think would be appropriate in mobile devices here is the code I got and it from https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FixedFadeOutMenu/

```
//fadeout script
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop != 0)
            $('.fadeout').stop().animate({'opacity':'0.2'},400);
        else    
            $('.fadeout').stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},400);
    });

    $('.fadeout').hover(
        function (e) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if(scrollTop != 0){
                $('.fadeout').stop().animate({'opacity':'1'},400);
            }
        },
        function (e) {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if(scrollTop != 0){
                $('.fadeout').stop().animate({'opacity':'0.2'},400);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

I am open to javascript/jquery/plugin but would prefer a css only solution

Any help much appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried not displaying that class `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { .a {display: none;}}`

Comment: @WhiteHox not very helpful

Comment: What do you mean by "disable" the class? Can you show us your code? If you want to hide the element, you can use `display: none` in that media query. If you want to disable styles associated with `.A` you can wrap its original styles in a `(min-width: 787px)` block, or cancel out its styles one by one with default values.

Comment: then try `display: none !important;`

Comment: ok i explain the class does something regarding " $(window).scrollTop(); " in jquery which i dont think would be appropriate in mobile devices

Answer (score 2):

Why not just define the CSS for the class using the opposite media query?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 787px) {
  .A {
    // style rules here.
  }
}
```

Comment: the class was fade in jquery for a special purpose again not very helpful

Comment: Then the only way you can do it in CSS, is by disabling specific style rules, as suggested by VaugenWakeling. You can inspect the style rules of the class in the developer tools, and reset them accordingly.

Comment: ok i explain the class does something regarding " $(window).scrollTop(); " in jquery which i dont think would be appropriate in mobile devices

Comment: Right, so you mean that there are no style rules to disable. The class is used just so that an element can be referenced from JS, is that correct? If that's the case, then no, you cannot do anything using CSS. I suggest you take a look at [Window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia).

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the parameters you want by using !important

**I.E.**
Greater that 768px

```
.A {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Less then 768px

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 786px) {
.A {
margin:0px !important;
width: 120px !important;
}
}
```

Comment: the class was fade in jquery for a special purpose again not very helpful

Comment: ok i explain the class does something regarding " $(window).scrollTop(); " in jquery which i dont think would be appropriate in mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you mean by disable but you can use `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`. With `visibility:hidden` the element still takes up space on the page, you just can't see it while `display:none` will not render the element at all.

Answer (score -1):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 787px) {
    .A {
        display: none !important;  /* If you just want it hidden */
        pointer-events: none; /* If you don't want the user to be able to click */
    }
}
```

Comment: display none is not disabling a class - it's hiding that element

Comment: the class was fade in jquery for a special purpose again not very helpful

Comment: ok i explain the class does something regarding " $(window).scrollTop(); " in jquery which i dont think would be appropriate in mobile devices

Comment: @AsifAli - helpful tip for using StackOverflow:  add your clarification and detail in your original post / question by editing it, instead of repeating for each comment thread under submitted answers.